# Input field to url

Tags: html

This might be a simple thing for you guys but need support on below..
Will have an input field:
"Input your tracking number" and when the # is entered (let's say 123456) and clicking the button should link to a certain webpage: https://xxxcargo.com/tracking/123456
this simple... but need your support on how to input in html
thanks in advance
I am a newbie with no solid experience and checked some of the similar posts but were not exactly what i need

Comment: javascript can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for this.

Steps which you can think of for a similar problem

1. Use Event listeners to listen to submit of the form
2. On submit, get the data from the input of the form
3. Open a new tab with the desired link.

Here is how you can implement your solution.

```js
document.querySelector("#myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //stop form from submitting
  window.open(
    " https://xxxcargo.com/tracking/" +
      document.querySelector("#myInput").value,
    "_blank"
  );
});
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
<div>
 <div id="input_form">
  <form id="myForm">
    Enter your TrackingID <br>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="fullname"></input>
   <br>
   <button  type="submit">Track Now</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

NOTE: StackOverflow might prevent the code from opening a new tab. But try this locally it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a working JSFiddle that implements this functionality](https://jsfiddle.net/op18dxyu/30/)

HTML

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="tracking" type="text" placeholder="Tracking Number" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const tracking = document.getElementById("tracking").value;
  const href = `https://xxxcargo.com/tracking/${tracking}`;
  console.log("Redirecting to", href);
  window.location.replace(href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right then,
when the user types a string with a trailing hashtag in the end, the string becomes the path of the domain `https://xxxcargo.com/tracking/here-goes-path`. If that's what you want then

The Code (HTML with JavaScript)

```
<input id="input-bar" type="text"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById('input-bar').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        if (this.value.endsWith('#')) {
            var domain = 'https://xxxcargo.com/tracking/'; // The Domain, Trailing Slash At The End Is Important
            var path = this.value.substring(0, (this.value.length - 1));
            window.location = domain + path;
        }
    });
</script>
```